# Deleting a value selected from a combobox in php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to delete a certain selected value from my MYSQL database in php..

[delete.php]

```
<form name="delete" method="POST" action="d3l3t3d.php">
    <select name="eBox" id="nname" style="width: 290px; height:40px;">
    <?php
    mysql_connect("a","b","") or die("Wrong username or password");
    mysql_select_db("TABLE") or die( "Unable to select database");
    $query = "Select * From list";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
    { 
    $name = $row['name']; 
    echo "<option>" . $name . "</option>"; 
    } 
    echo "</select><br/><br/>"
    ?>
```

[d3l3t3d.php]

```
<?php
   $namez = $_POST['nname'];
   $name = mysql_real_escape_string($namez);
   mysql_connect("a","b",
   "") or die("Wrong username or password");
   mysql_select_db("TABLE") or die( "Unable to select database");
mysql_query("DELETE FROM list WHERE name='$name'");
?>
```

I get the following ERROR:

> Notice: Undefined index: nname in C:\xampp\htdocs\folder\d3l3t3d.php
>   on line 2

Comment: You're missing a semi-colon at the end of the line here `echo "</select><br/><br/>";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$namez = $_POST['nname'];` should be `$namez = $_POST['ebox'];`

You select elements via their name, not id.

Answer (score 0):

`$namez = $_POST['nname'];` should be `$namez = $_POST['eBox'];`

The error: `Undefined index: nname in C:\xampp\htdocs\folder\d3l3t3d.php on line 2`, means its searching for a element with attribute `name = "nname"`, which of course, does not exist. you had `name = "eBox"`.

just a small typo :)