# Multiple Image upload and save path to database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql, database

I am working on a script that uploads multiple images and saves the path to database to fetch the images in each record separately. The images are uploaded well but the image name in the database are stored in the following format uploads/image_name.png which should be actually just image_name.png. Moreover when I upload multiple images a separate record is created in the database for each image. I want to display them in the same field. Here is the code I am using to upload the file to the database using php.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $j = 0; //Variable for indexing uploaded image 

    $target_path = "uploads/"; //Declaring Path for uploaded images

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['file']['name']); $i++) {//loop to get individual element from the array

        $validextensions = array("jpeg", "jpg", "png");  //Extensions which are allowed
        $ext = explode('.', basename($_FILES['file']['name'][$i]));//explode file name from dot(.) 
        $file_extension = end($ext); //store extensions in the variable
        $img = implode('',$_FILES['file']['name']);
        $target_path = $target_path . md5(uniqid()) . "." . $ext[count($ext) - 1];
        $title = (!empty($_POST['ad_title']))?$_POST['ad_title']:null;
        $cat = (!empty($_POST['ad_cat']))?$_POST['ad_cat']:null;
        $des = (!empty($_POST['ad_des']))?$_POST['ad_des']:null;
        $name = (!empty($_POST['ad_name']))?$_POST['ad_name']:null;
        $email = (!empty($_POST['ad_email']))?$_POST['ad_email']:null;
        $phone = (!empty($_POST['ad_phone']))?$_POST['ad_phone']:null;
        $state = (!empty($_POST['ad_state']))?$_POST['ad_state']:null;

        //set the target path with a new name of image
        $j = $j + 1;//increment the number of uploaded images according to the files in array       

      if (($_FILES["file"]["size"][$i] < 1024000) //Approx. 1mb files can be uploaded.
                && in_array($file_extension, $validextensions)) {
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i], $target_path)) {

                $sql = "INSERT INTO ad_posting(img_name, ad_title, ad_cat, ad_des, ad_name, ad_email, ad_phone, ad_state)VALUES('$target_path', '$title','$cat','$des','$name','$email','$phone','$state')";
                $frc = mysql_query($sql);
                if ($frc){
                echo "Success";
                }else{
                echo "Not Successful";
                }

                echo $j. ').<span id="noerror">Image uploaded successfully!.</span><br/><br/>';
            } else {//if file was not moved.
                echo $j. ').<span id="error">please try again!.</span><br/><br/>';
            }
        } else {//if file size and file type was incorrect.
            echo $j. ').<span id="error">***Invalid file Size or Type***</span><br/><br/>';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

This is the javascript code i m using.

```
var abc = 0; //Declaring and defining global increement variable

$(document).ready(function() {

//To add new input file field dynamically, on click of "Add More Files" button below function will be executed
    $('#add_more').click(function() {
        $(this).before($("<div/>", {id: 'filediv'}).fadeIn('slow').append(
                $("<input/>", {name: 'file[]', type: 'file', id: 'file'}),        
                $("<br/><br/>")
                ));
    });

//following function will executes on change event of file input to select different file   
$('body').on('change', '#file', function(){
            if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
                 abc += 1; //increementing global variable by 1

                var z = abc - 1;
                var x = $(this).parent().find('#previewimg' + z).remove();
                $(this).before("<div id='abcd"+ abc +"' class='abcd'><img id='previewimg" + abc + "' src=''/></div>");

                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
                reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);

                $(this).hide();
                $("#abcd"+ abc).append($("<img/>", {id: 'img', src: 'x.png', alt: 'delete'}).click(function() {
                $(this).parent().parent().remove();
                }));
            }
        });

//To preview image     
    function imageIsLoaded(e) {
        $('#previewimg' + abc).attr('src', e.target.result);
    };

    $('#upload').click(function(e) {
        var name = $(":file").val();
        if (!name)
        {
            alert("First Image Must Be Selected");
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

What is the error I am making? Please help me out solve the query.

Comment: What library or script are you using for this?

Comment: because you are inserting `$target_path` as filename use `$_FILES['file']['name']` instead of it in insert query.

Comment: the script have the line $target_path = $_FILES['file']['name'];

Comment: @DelightedD0D i have edited the code. Please check.

Comment: @CoDe MurDeRer This saves the original name of the file. I want to save the renamed file name without the "uploads/". And I also want all the uploaded image to be saved in the same record not in different record. What can I do for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from uploads/image_name.png to image_name.png.

```
$filename = 'uploads/image_name.png';
basename($filename);
```

in your sql

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO ad_posting(img_name, ad_title, ad_cat, ad_des, ad_name, ad_email, ad_phone, ad_state)VALUES('$target_path', '$title','$cat','$des','$name','$email','$phone','$state')";
```

if $target_path have the vale uploads/image_name.png then

```
$target_path = basename($target_path);
```

if you want the name of all images in the same field you can use implode().

Comment: i have already applied implode().. you can see that in my code.

Comment: There was a mistake in my $targetpath now corrected. This code renames the image. Now tell me what to do.

Comment: you have the sql inside the for, put it out

Comment: Thanks. Your code helped me solve the "uploads/" problem. Now the image is renamed and directly saved to the database. But one problem persists. Each images should be saved in the same row but here it creates a different row for each image.

Comment: I cant take the sql our of for loop. That wont help. Doing that will abort the script from getting the image name and it will leave the field undefined as undefined index....

Comment: if you want execute your sql once, put it out of the for. But how many columns do you have ? You will need one per image

Comment: I think that you must create another table where you can store the images (relation 1-m from ad_posting to ad_posting_image)

Comment: you got some advance?

Comment: @ShubhamJha I edit my code, test it and tell me if you could solve your problem.

Comment: Dont worry... but I need a help.. New Issue.. 

How to delete a mysql row from the <select></select> tag? I mean my categories are displayed in <select><option value="<from database>"></option></select>... I want to delete a single row by id.. how can I delete?

Comment: @ShubhamJha read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15858367/deleting-a-value-selected-from-a-combobox-in-php-mysql

Comment: I know about deleting. i want to delete from the select tag.

Comment: @ShubhamJha see oyher example here http://board.phpbuilder.com/showthread.php?10361923-RESOLVED-Deleting-and-Updating-a-MySql-entry-using-a-select-menu

Comment: I already solved it dude... Hey dude connect with me on facebook... my email id is shubhamjha1000@gmail.com

Comment: this is a test to verify that I a human? Why you don't check as correct?

Comment: I joke ;-) Don't worry